# C++ list not recognized as a container?

Tags: c++, list, iterator

This is a more specific question about a problem I seem to be running into for this assignment. Basically, the instructions are to create a list using the STL (instead of a linked list). In the examples I see stuff like:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

vector<char> container = { 'A','B','C','D','E' };

    cout << "Print vector using an iterator: ";
    vector<char>::iterator iter = container.begin();    
    while (iter != container.end())
    {
        cout << *iter << " ";
        ++iter;
    }
    cout << endl;                   // OUTPUT: A B C D E
```

While I try to do in the Main.cpp file of my assignment:

```
#include "AnyList.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    AnyList list1, list2;

    list1.insertFront(10);
    list1.insertFront(11);
    list1.insertFront(12);
    list1.insertFront(13);
    list1.insertFront(14);

    list<int>::const_iterator iter = list1.begin();
```

AnyList.h

```
#ifndef ANYLIST_H
#define ANYLIST_H

#include<iostream>
#include <string>   
#include <list>

#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

class AnyList
{
public:

    AnyList();

    int getNumOfElem() const;

    void insertFront(int data);
    void forwardPrint();

private:
    list<int> *ptr; 
};

#endif
```

AnyList.cpp

```
#include "AnyList.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

AnyList::AnyList() 
{

}

int AnyList::getNumOfElem() const
{
    return static_cast<int>(ptr->size());
}

void AnyList::insertFront(int data)
{
    ptr->push_front(data);
}

void AnyList::forwardPrint()
{
    list<int>::const_iterator i;
    for (i = ptr->begin(); i != ptr->end(); ++i)
    {
        cout << *i << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

In the main file, for the line:

list::const_iterator iter = list1.begin();

I get an error saying that "begin" is not a member of AnyList. I looked up what the issue could be and it's seems like it's caused by list1 not being an actual container? From what it looks like it should be a container for a list created by insertFront, but it's not recognizing it.

Is there a mistake with how the list is implemented? Or is insertFront not done correctly? Actually the whole reason why I tried to run the program with that line is to see if insertFront is working properly, but right now I have no clue where the mistake is. Most of the examples I've seen are declared in one file without having to implement it in a class so this assignment is extremely confusing at this point.

Also to clear up some potential misunderstandings:
- the AnyList class, the private member variable, and the getNumOfElem function were already included in the file and getNumOfElem is provided as an actual implementation example.

Edit: Also I do need some help on how to properly initialize the variable "ptr" here, because supposedly that could also be the issue that's preventing the lot of this from working.

Comment: The issue is that `AnyList` literally does not provide a `begin` method. I mean, you have the declaration right there: It supports `getNumOfElem`, `insertFront`, `forwardPrint`. That's it.

Comment: Maybe try to do this assignment yourself? You seem to be trying to get it written for you, one silly mistake at a time.

Comment: I'm trying to do that and this is that start of it. I mean if I knew how to fix the problems that come up these questions wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Learn some basic C++ and figure it out yourself. SO isn't the place for these kind of questions.

Comment: It's okay if you don't want to help with my questions anymore. There are many people here who are willing to help so you're wasting your time policing here.

Answer (score 0):

```
AnyList list1, list2;

list<int>::const_iterator iter = list1.begin();
```

This code calls the `begin()` method of the `list1` object. `list1` is an instance of the `AnyList` class.

For this to work, the `AnyList` class must implement a class method called `begin()`, that returns a `list<int>::const_iterator`.

The declaration of the `AnyList` class, shown in the question, indicates that this class does not implement any method called `begin()`. The `AnyList` class implements only three class methods, named `getNumOfElem()`, `insertFront()`, and `forwardPrint()`.

A container is not some kind of an auto-magical concept in C++, that automatically works with any class. A container is just an ordinary class of its own (a template class, but that's not relevant here), with ordinary methods.

If `AnyList` class should behave like a container, and work with the rest of C++ library algorithms and templates that can be used with container, the `AnyList` class must meet all requirements for a C++ container, which includes defining its own `begin()` and `end()` methods, and other methods, as well as defining some inner types.

Comment: I see, thanks for the input! Why is it that it needs to be defined in that class but not outside of the class (like in the example)?

Comment: What example? There is no example here that defines `begin()`/`end()`, et al. "outside of the class".

Comment: In the first block of code in my post (with the vectors). None of the example files (or online examples) I see have begin() defined in any of them.

Comment: The first block of code shown does not define anything. Words mean things. "Define" doesn't mean "use". The first block of code uses a `begin()` method, it does not define it. `std::vector` is defined in the `#include <vector>` header. That header defines a template class called `vector`, with `begin()` and `end()` methods, and many other methods too. That's why you can use a `std::vector` method named `begin()`.

Comment: Even if you get past these issues, the code will STILL not work, because `AnyList` declares its inner list as a pointer that never points to anything valid. The constructor needs a `ptr = new list<int>;` statement (and you also need a copy constructor, copy assignment operator, and destructor, too. See [Rule of Three](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))). Otherwise, change the declaration to `list<int> ptr;` instead, and adjust all uses of `ptr->` to `ptr.` accordingly. Or, just get rid of `AnyList` and use `std::list` directly where needed.